# How to set the MaxDequeueCount at the Queue Level

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have an Azure WebJob listening to multiple queues...

I can specify the MaxDequeueCount at the job level...

```
    config.UseTimers();
    config.Queues.BatchSize = 32;
    config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 6;
```

What the best way to set MaxDequeueCounts at the queue level? I know I can get the actual dequeue count and send it to the poison queue "manually" but I was wondering if this can be done in a better way...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to set different configuration for different queue trigger functions, you could implement your own QueueProcessorFactory and reset some configurations of context based on the queue name.

```
public class MyQueueProcessorFactory : IQueueProcessorFactory
{
    public  QueueProcessor Create(QueueProcessorFactoryContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        if (context.Queue.Name == "queue1")
        {
            context.MaxDequeueCount = 2;
        }
        else if (context.Queue.Name == "queue2")
        {
            context.MaxDequeueCount = 4;
        }
        return new QueueProcessor(context);
    }
}
```

To use the custom QueueProcessorFactory, we need to set the QueueProcessorFactory property as following.

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.Queues.QueueProcessorFactory = new MyQueueProcessorFactory();
JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
```